# Use of HTTP RESTful methods GET/POST/etc. Are they superfluous?

Tags: rest, http, post, get

*What is the value of RESTful “methods”* (ie. GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, etc.)?

*Why not just make every client use the “GET” method w/ any/all relevant params, headers, requestbodies, JSON,etc. etc.?*

On the server side, the response to each method is custom & independently coded!

For example, *what difference does it make to issue a database query via GET instead of POST?*

I understand that GET is for queries that don’t change the DB (or anything else?).
And POST is for calls that do make changes.

But, near as I can tell, the RESTful standard doesn’t prevent one to code up a server response to GET and issue a stored procedure call that indeed DOES change the DB.

Vice versa… the RESTful standard doesn’t prevent one to code up a server response to POST  and issue a stored procedure call that indeed does NOT change the ANYTHING!

I’m not arguing that a midtier (HTTP) “RESTlike” layer is necessary. It clearly is.

Let's say I'm wrong (and I may be). Isn't it still likely that there are numerous REST servers violating the proper use of these protocols suffering ZERO repercussions?

The following do not directly address my questions but merely dance uncomfortably around it like an acidhead stoner at a Dead concert:

[Different Models for RESTful GET and POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001927/different-models-for-restful-get-and-post)

[RESTful - GET or POST - what to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453945/restful-get-or-post-what-to-do)

[GET vs POST in REST Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046927/get-vs-post-in-rest-web-service)

[PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)

I just spent ~80 hours trying to communicate a PATCH to my REST server (older Android Java doesn't recognize the newer PATCH so I had to issue a stupid kluge HTTP-OVERIDE-METHOD in the header). A POST would have worked fine but the sysop wouldn't budge because he respects REST.

I just don’t understand why to bother with each individual method.  They don't seem to have much impact on Idempotence. They seem to be mere *guidelines*. And if you "violate" these "guidelines" they give someone else a chance to point a feckless finger at you. ***But so what?***
***Aren't these guidelines more trouble than they're worth?***
I'm just confused. Please excuse the stridency of my post.

***Aren’t REST GET/POST/etc. methods superfluous?***

Comment: Because that would be RPC, not REST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the value of RESTful “methods” (ie. GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, etc.)?

First, a clarification.  Those aren't RESTful methods; those are HTTP methods.  The web is a reference implementation (for the most part) of the REST architectural style.

Which means that the authoritative answers to your questions are documented in the HTTP specification.

> But, near as I can tell, the RESTful standard doesn’t prevent one to code up a server response to GET and issue a stored procedure call that indeed DOES change the DB.

The HTTP specification designates certain methods as being [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1).  Casually, this designates that a method is read only; the client is not responsible for any side effects that may occur on the server.

> The purpose of distinguishing between safe and unsafe methods is to allow automated retrieval processes (spiders) and cache performance optimization (pre-fetching) to work without fear of causing harm.

But you are right, the HTTP standard doesn't prevent you from changing your database in response to a GET request.  In fact, it even calls out specifically a case where you may choose to do that:

> a safe request initiated by selecting an advertisement on the Web will often have the side effect of charging an advertising account.

The HTTP specification also designates certain methods as being [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2)

> Of the request methods defined by this specification, PUT, DELETE, and safe request methods are idempotent.

The motivation for having idempotent methods?  Unreliable networks

> Idempotent methods are distinguished because the request can be repeated automatically if a communication failure occurs before the client is able to read the server's response.

Note that the client here might not be the user agent, but an intermediary component (like a reverse proxy) participating in the conversation.

Thus, if I'm writing a user agent, or a component, that needs to talk to your server, and your server conforms to the definition of methods in the HTTP specification, then I don't need to know anything about your application protocol to know how to correctly handle lost messages when the method is GET, PUT, or DELETE.

On the other hand, POST doesn't tell me anything, and since the unacknowledged message may still be on its way to you, it is dangerous to send a duplicate copy of the message.

> Isn't it still likely that there are numerous REST servers violating the proper use of these protocols suffering ZERO repercussions?

Absolutely -- remember, *the* reference implementation of hypermedia is HTML, and HTML doesn't include support PUT or DELETE.  If you want to afford a hypermedia control that invokes an unsafe operation, while still conforming to the HTTP and HTML standards, the POST is your only option.

> Aren't these guidelines more trouble than they're worth?

Not really?  They offer real value in reliability, and the extra complexity they add to the mix is pretty minimal.

> I just don’t understand why to bother with each individual method. They don't seem to have much impact on idempotence.

They don't impact it, they *communicate* it.

The server already knows which of its resources are [idempotent receivers](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/IdempotentReceiver.html).  It's the client and the [intermediary components](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_3) that need that information.  The HTTP specification gives you the ability to communicate that information for free to any other compliant component.

Using the maximally appropriate method for each request means that you can deploy your solution into a topology of commodity components, and it **just works**.

Alternatively, you can give up reliable messaging.  Or you can write a bunch of custom code in your components to tell them explicitly which of your endpoints are idempotent receivers.

**POST vs PATCH**

Same song, different verse.  If a resource supports [OPTIONS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.7), [GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1), and [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789), then I can discover everything I need to know to execute a partial update, and I can do so using the same commodity implementation I use everywhere else.

Achieving the same result with POST is a whole lot more work.  For instance, you need some mechanism for communicating to the client that POST has partial update semantics, and what media-types are accepted when patching a specific resource.

> What do I lose by making each call on the client GET and the server honoring such just by paying attention to the request and not the method?

Conforming user-agents are allowed to assume that GET is *safe*.  If you have side effects (writes) on endpoints accessible via GET, then the agent is allowed to pre-fetch the endpoint as an optimization -- the side effects start firing even though nobody expects it.

If the endpoint isn't an idempotent receiver, then you have to consider that the GET calls can happen more than once.

Furthermore, the user agent and intermediary components are allowed to make assumptions about [caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) -- requests that you expect to get all the way through to the server don't, because conforming components along the way are permitted to server replies out of their own cache.

To ice the cake, you are introducing another additional risk; *undefined behavior*.

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

Where I believe you are coming from, though I'm not certain, is more of an RPC point of view.  Client sends a message, server responds; so long as both participants in the conversation have a common understanding of the semantics of the message, does it matter if the text in the message says "GET" or "POST" or "PATCH"?  Of course not.

RPC is a *fantastic* choice when it fits the problem you are trying to solve.

**But...**

RPC at web scale is hard.  Can your team deliver that? can your team deliver with cost effectiveness?

On the other hand, HTTP at scale is comparatively simple; there's an *enormous* ecosystem of goodies, using scalable architectures, that are stable, tested, well understood, and inexpensive.  The tires are well and truly kicked.

You and your team hardly have to do anything; a bit of block and tackle to comply with the HTTP standards, and from that point on you can concentrate on delivering business value while you fall into the pit of success.

Comment: >Thus, if I'm writing a user agent, or a component, that needs to talk to your server, and your server conforms to the definition of methods in the HTTP specification, then I don't need to know anything about your application protocol to know how to correctly handle lost messages when the method is GET, PUT, or DELETE."

what happens if a message gets "lost"? what does "lost" mean?   

If I issue a GET and then shutdown before I receive a response is that "lost"? what happens then?

Comment: Lost means: I don't get a response to my request.  Maybe you went down, maybe my/your network went down, maybe my message got routed to New Horizons, or maybe your response did.   From the point of view of the client, I have no way to distinguish "my request didn't reach you" from "your response didn't reach me".  If I want to ensure that you receive the message at least once, I need to resend it until a wild ack appears.

Comment: If *I* shut down before receiving your response, then either it wasn't a priority, or I'm going to identify the response as lost when I restart.  Which is to say, my durable state is going to allow me to reconstruct which messages were pending when I shut down.

Comment: So, I take these two responses to mean "REST neither provides nor prevents anything"...?

Comment: Is there no objection to the use of the word "guidelines"?

Comment: >Achieving the same result with POST is a whole lot more work.<
How so? Just issue all of the same calls using POST (or GET or whatever), the server can ignore the method and just pay attention to the request itself.
Sorry, I just don't understand. In the end, the server is paying attention to the request itself and NOT the method. The method seems, and, as you've so much admitted, is, irrelevant.

Comment: What do I lose by making each call on the client GET and the server honoring such just by paying attention to the request and not the method?

Comment: Well, you've pointed out that I need to consider RPC vs. REST. THANK YOU. I needed that and am now doing so.
But I need to think on your defense of REST for awhile.

Comment: I googled RPC vs. REST and am reviewing:
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/181176/when-are-rpc-ish-approaches-more-appropriate-than-rest  
https://sites.google.com/site/wagingguerillasoftware/rest-series/what-is-restful-rest-vs-rpc  
https://apihandyman.io/do-you-really-know-why-you-prefer-rest-over-rpc/

Comment: You're welcome -- sorry it took so long to realize that was the question you were asking.